# Remove horizontal line when swiping across a collection view / carousel view with page control (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, carousel, uipagecontrol

I am using a standard UICollectionView, UIPageControl and using this custom carousel flow layout.

> https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout

I am unsure which property is actually triggering this, whether it is related to the collection view itself or the carousel..

[image]

How can I remove this grey horizontal line that appears when I swipe left or right? It remains on screen for a few seconds.. But I wan't to get rid of it all together.

Thanks

Edit:

Fixed by adding this after initialisation of the collection view..

```
collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

Comment: What *"grey horizontal line"* are you referring to? I grabbed the `UPCarouselFlowLayout` project from GitHub, and running the sample demo app I don't see any line.

Comment: @DonMag can you see the grey line that is above the name label, in this case the "SADIO"'.. 

This appears whenever I swipe left or right.. Unsure if it is a property of the collectionview or page control or the carousel, but I havent specifically set it anywhere in the code..

Comment: Since it is not there in the demo app, then it's something you have done. Is it part of your image? Is it the cell background? Is it part of the label, or the view holding the label? Use `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect your app and find out where it's coming from.

Comment: @DonMag By using that debugging view hierarchy, the line was attributed to the collection view.. To fix it, I set the .showsHorizontalScrollIndicator to false.. 

Didn't know it was possible to debug views like that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set collectionview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator to false after initialising it in the view controller class..

Like this:

```
collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```